# Create a dynamic table of contents with page numbers in HTML

Tags: python, html, markdown

I have a python script that converts a MarkDown text to HTML (with some additions and styling of my own), The markdown code includes headers and bookmarks, I want the script to automatically create a table of contents that would include the page numbers (like you might find in a printed book for example) based on the assumption that the document would be printed on standard A4 sheets. Is it possible?

Thanks...
YK

Comment: HTML doesn't really have any concept of "pages." Therefore, there is no way to get page numbers. You might want to explore html to pdf conversion tools. xhtml2pdf and weasyprint come to mind, although there may be others.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `.rst` or `.md` files with [sphinx](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/)? You can have a table of contents and it will generate your html and you can do all kinds of fancy stuff with it. An overwhelming majority of python documentation is written using it. It looks like they account for `A4` paper size as well in some cases.

From the sphinx docs [environment variables section](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/man/sphinx-build.html#environment-variables):

[image]

Comment: Well... "Why not use .md files with sphinx?" to begin with - I wasn't aware that such a tool exists, but also for other reasons:
1. The users of my tool, i.e. the ones that will write the .md files are not very tech savvy and are not developers, so I had to come up with a tool that even they can use.
2. The tool I developed doesn't only convert .md files to .html files, the tool also generate another .html file based on some sort of a merge between a selected group of .md files and a .yaml file that contains references to bookmarks in the .md files.

Is there another way I can do that?

Comment: Interesting :). Yeah that definitely sounds a lot likes sphinx. I would at least look at sphinx and see if you can make it a little more user-friendly (it kinda already is, but I understand your predicament :) ) so as to not have to develop an entire tool yourself from scratch. That is a painful experience and honestly you would most likely end up maintaining it since it is a custom nuanced solution, which you may not want to do in the long run.

Comment: [Here](https://www.alkaline-ml.com/pmdarima/) is an example of some sphinx documentation using `.rst` files, but it is the same procedure with `.md` files. You can view the page source to see the raw file and [here](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/quickstart.html) is the quickstart. Hopefully it works for you and save you the headache of maintaining an inhouse solution. Plus there is a wider community of users of sphinx from which to draw support :).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick replies! I think that this not exactly what I meant by TOC, currently, my tool generate a long HTML file, what I'm hoping to achieve is to add a page as the first page that will contain something like this in every line: <header name>..............4\n
\t<sub-header name>.....5\n
and so on. Is this doable?